# Android fragments setup with a listView. Can't get it to work with ONLY ONE ACTIVITY

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-listview

I have 2 fragments (different classes).

```
public class TodoMainFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);    
    return v;
}
}
```

and

```
public class TodoFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_todo, container, false);
    return v;
}
}
```

These both have an XML-file with the layout of each fragment. (This is for my TodoMainFragment). This is where my id=gradientLayout is.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/todo_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#292A2C"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.todo.MainActivity" >
<requestFocus />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="changeViewToNewTodo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/gradientBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have a main_activity XML-file that is just an empty FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Then onCreate() in my MainActivity I have

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

    TodoMainFragment mainFragment = new TodoMainFragment();
    TodoFragment editFragment = new TodoFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, editFragment);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
    transaction.commit();

    //DB and lists
    db = new TodoDbHelper(this);
    todos = db.getAllTodos();
    nrOfTodos = todos.size();



    //For ListView    
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gradientBackground);
    mAdapter = new TodoAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_view_item_default);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    createTodoItems();

}
```

The problem is that my mListView is null. From what I understood (which is probably wrong), shouldn't

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
```

make it possible to get the gradientBackground? Now my app crashes on launch with a nullpointer exception but if I change the setContentView to activity_list (the XML for TodoMainFragment) it works. Any ideas are highly appreciated. I'm pretty new to this so go easy on me. :)

Comment: can you put activity_main.xml

Comment: The listview is implemented on fragment XML, not on Activity... thats why is null.

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash that is the activity_main.xml. I just accidentally wrote main_activity.

Comment: @PedroHawk i know that it's the reason but I don't know how to fix it. I thought it would work to add my fragments to my activity_main...

Comment: why dont u implement the listviews inside each fragment who have listview?